# Language as barrier to concepts

Tags: logic, reference-request

Can the limitations of language be considered a barrier in conveying a philosophical concept? How can an idea that resists linguistic formulation be conveyed without losing the essence?

Is there a recognized philosophical way of approaching this problem?  If not, are there philosophers who have tackled it directly?

Comment: Any chance I could persuade you to expand and clarify your question a bit?

Comment: Just in passing, the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis seems relevant here; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity

Comment: The question isn't naive, but it is very poorly formed.

*Can Language be considered an impediment in conveying a concept in philosophy?* No.  Language is the only means by which concepts, properly speaking, are conveyed.  

*How can an idea be conveyed without losing the essence?*  Wait, how did we get from "concepts" to "ideas"?  And what "essence" are you worried about losing?

*In other words can an idea be only experienced??*  Is it proper to say that an "idea" is "experienced" (as opposed to "an idea is thought"?) Can you indicate an example of an "idea" that you have "experienced"?

Answer (score 1):

Of course language is somewhat of a barrier when it comes to describing many things, certain things more than others. For example, the aesthetic beauty of a sunset or the exquisite taste of a fine wine to a seasoned taster might be somewhat difficult to convey, particularly to people who aren't familiar with such things. But I'm pretty sure there's less impediment with things like basic mathematics and physics, although I'm sure there are somewhat arcane concepts in either field that are equally challenging to express.

However, unless you are some sort of dualist, physicalism—which accounts for all mental states as physical brain states—leaves the door open for **accessing** what goes on in people's minds (in other words, our minds are not inherently available only to ourselves). Concordantly, with sufficient understanding of the brain and sufficiently advanced technology, it should in theory be possible in the future to record the precise brain state of a person, and translate the exact representation of that idea into a form that is more readily exchanged (whether by viewing it in a home theater system or experiencing directly via an analogous process). Some might dismiss such ideas as speculative, and we are admittedly quite far from this technology and understanding, but it is logically sound. That is, if you are a physicalist, *you have to believe this is possible.*

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly a restriction to philosophy that language acts as a restriction. We have all sorts of ideas in our heads for which language somehow seems not enough to convey. We can use pictures, hand movements, actions themselves to convey an idea. Some philosophy can use language so vaguely that it is not stating literally the thoughts that the author is trying to get across but the author hopes that cultural knowledge and history of the topic being discussed is enough to disambiguate.

The language may not be expressive enough to evoke ideas exactly enough, but there is still the desire to remove things as imprecise as pictures or other artifacts and replace with language because language tends to be more accurate (and checkable) than other methods. Having someone throw a rock at you might convince you of the reality of the outside world, or it might just make you think they're a jerk.